# Can m2e be configured to download plugin sources too?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm using Eclipse Juno with m2e 1.4.0.  I have m2e configured to download sources and javadocs which works fine for my dependency artifacts.  However m2e does not seem to download sources for any of my defined plugins.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse / m2e to download the sources for the plugins as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m2e doesn't download sources or javadoc for plugins. However, you can temporarily add the plugin as a normal dependency, ask Eclipse to download the sources/javadoc, and then remove it again.